# How would you implement shouldComponentUpdate using useEffect in React?

Tags: reactjs, state, react-hooks, high-order-component, react-lifecycle-hooks

I was reading the React docs and it recommended if you had some props that would be changed frequently, a good life cycle method to use would be [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#examples).

My question is how would you use the [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) approach with a functional component like the following?

This is my functional component:

```
function GenericIsUserLoggedInLink({ isLoggedIn, logOutUser, route, anchorText }) {

    const [setProps] = useState({isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn, route: route, anchorText:anchorText });
    console.log('setProps', setProps);

 useEffect((nextProps, nextState) => {
    if (setProps.isLoggedIn !== nextProps.setProps.isLoggedIn) {
      return true;
    }
    if (setProps.route !== nextProps.setProps.route) {
      return true;
    }
    if (setProps.anchorText !== nextProps.setProps.anchorText) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });

 if (isLoggedIn) {
  if (anchorText === undefined) {
   return <Link href="/"><a onClick={() => logOutUser()}>Log out!</a></Link>
  } else if (anchorText) {
   return <Link href={route}><a >{anchorText}</a></Link>
  }
 } else {
  if (route === "/login") {
     return  <Link href="/login"><a >Log in!</a></Link>
  }
  return null
 }
}
```

That was my take, but it didn't work! HA! Is there anyone who can provide insight?

**UPDATE**
I followed Shubham's prescription—but ran into this?

[image]

SO i did this...
But it feels hacky:
I guess its not as I am leveraging [lexical scoping](https://medium.com/@nickbalestra/javascripts-lexical-scope-hoisting-and-closures-without-mystery-c2324681d4be)

```
var comparator;
const GenericIsUserLoggedInLink = React.memo(({ isLoggedIn, logOutUser, route, anchorText }) => {
 comparator = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  if (prevProps.isLoggedIn !== nextProps.setProps.isLoggedIn) {
      return true;
    }
    if (prevProps.isLoggedIn !== nextProps.setProps.route) {
      return true;
    }
    if (prevProps.anchorText !== nextProps.setProps.anchorText) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}

   if (isLoggedIn) {
      if (anchorText === undefined) {
       return <Link href="/"><a onClick={() => logOutUser()}>Log out!</a></Link>
      } else if (anchorText) {
       return <Link href={route}><a >{anchorText}</a></Link>
      }
   } else {
      if (route === "/login") {
         return  <Link href="/login"><a >Log in!</a></Link>
      }
      return null
   }
}, comparator);
```

Comment: I am not sure if the return true/false in useEffect has any thing to do with the component rendering. Because, if we return a function in useEffect, it will be run as a clean up function, however, I don't think it has anything to do with a boolean.

Comment: also, I am not sure if the nextProps would be available inside a useEffect or not. So, I would leave it to better people to clarify

Comment: Why would you need that "setProps" state and those checks in a first place? You never use that state in render phase and you useEffect does nothing useful. What does go wrong if you just leave `if (isLoggedIn) { ... }` part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useEffect` is not an appropriate hook as an alternative to `shouldComponentUpdate` for functional components.

Rather you need to use **[React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)** in order to prevent re-rendering. Also you don't need to maintain a state to compare previous and current props.

```
const comparator = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  if (prevProps.isLoggedIn !== nextProps.setProps.isLoggedIn) {
      return true;
    }
    if (prevProps.route !== nextProps.setProps.route) {
      return true;
    }
    if (prevProps.anchorText !== nextProps.setProps.anchorText) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}

const GenericIsUserLoggedInLink = React.memo(({ isLoggedIn, logOutUser, route, anchorText }) => {

   if (isLoggedIn) {
      if (anchorText === undefined) {
       return <Link href="/"><a onClick={() => logOutUser()}>Log out!</a></Link>
      } else if (anchorText) {
       return <Link href={route}><a >{anchorText}</a></Link>
      }
   } else {
      if (route === "/login") {
         return  <Link href="/login"><a >Log in!</a></Link>
      }
      return null
   }
}, comparator);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate it! I updated my question with your addition and what happened subsequently. So `React.memo` should speed things up? I imagine in `production` this would be speedier?

Comment: Watch out for the comparator function. When it returns true the component will not be re-redered. Call it areEqual or shouldNotRerender for better understanding.